# Need assistance regarding slide to unlock like animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I am using this code to create the slide to unlock like animation but I am unable to make it animate from `right to left`.

How can I make it start from right and animate to left?

```
-(void)slideToCancel {
    CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
    // Mask image ends with 0.15 opacity on both sides. Set the background color of the         layer
    // to the same value so the layer can extend the mask image.
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f  alpha:0.50f] CGColor];
    maskLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"slidetocancel.png"] CGImage];

    // Center the mask image on twice the width of the text layer, so it starts to the left
    // of the text layer and moves to its right when we translate it by width.
    maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
    maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(_slideToCancelLbl.frame.size.width * -1, 0.0f, _slideToCancelLbl.frame.size.width * 2, _slideToCancelLbl.frame.size.height);
    // Animate the mask layer's horizontal position
    CABasicAnimation *maskAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    maskAnim.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_slideToCancelLbl.frame.size.width];
    maskAnim.repeatCount = 1e100f;
    maskAnim.duration = 1.5f;
    [maskLayer addAnimation:maskAnim forKey:@"slideAnim"];
    _slideToCancelLbl.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use a negative byValue. However, the code you've posted is a canned animation, not one that responds to a slide gesture.

Comment: I tried the negative value but it is giving odd animation behaviour. I thing gravity is playing some role but how to make it animate from right to left.

Comment: I haven't tried using contentsGravity before. How about getting rid of byValue and setting fromValue and toValue instead?

Comment: Please can you update your last comment as an answer so I can uproot it and tick as correct answer.